# Terminal or Konsole?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, konsole

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 with KDE graphical environment. KDE has Konsole as terminal emulator. Now I have Terminal and Konsole both on my Ubuntu. My question is which one should I use to run command? Or they are equally good?

Comment: reviewers: I don't see how this is "opinion based" - it is a clear technical question if there is a fundamental difference between terminal emulators.

Comment: If you're satisfied with my answer and are bothered by the recent attention of reviewers, then you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark. Doing that will mark the question as answered thereby probably attracting less attention of reviewers. if you don't accept my answer your question will remain in the unanswered questions list and probably attracting attention every now and then.

Comment: actually I was waiting for few more opinions, but I think your ans is satisfactory. Thanks @wie5Ooma

Comment: Every terminal emulator is slightly different in how they display certain things, but this is usually a detail that you don't need to worry about. They all execute commands the same way, because they actually don't run any commands. They just hand character data to shell interpreters like `bash`, that interpret them as commands and run them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried both. They're equally good and there's no difference. I should stick with Konsole because it's part of Kubuntu/KDE.